# Error : Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I try to obtain all the users from a database and I get this error :

```
"Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'"
```

the code is the following :

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var users = Membership.GetAllUsers();
        return View(users);
    }
```

the code from webconfig is next :

```
<membership defaultProvider="SqlMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="SqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

Why this isn't working and why I keep getting the error ?

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple reason:

- Either by default you logged in into some other database then in which the procedure reside
- Procedure doesn't exists in your database at all (may be deleted?)
- You are changing the database somewhere internally.

Try manually logging into MSSMS with the login and password you are passing programmatically and do sp_helptext aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion and see if you get the procedure code?

Comment: For sure i am not logging in the wrong database. I am using SQL Server 2014 , where should i look for stored procedures?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `aspnet_regsql.exe` against your sql server to make sure that the tables and objects are created:

```
  aspnet_regsql.exe -S DBServerName -U DBLogin -P DBPassword -A all -d DBName
```

Comment: You can try run it wothout parameters and follow wizard steps, it's usually located : C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\[your framework version]\aspnet_regsql.exe

Comment: it doesn't work because my application doesn't use the tables the aspnet_regsql provides.

Comment: You use `SqlMembershipProvider`, which uses these tables and stored procedures. If you don't want your application to use these tables you need to switch to another `MembershipProvider` or implement your own provider.

Answer (score -1):

There Should be another action result  that is taking "users' as an argument.